# How to include multiple TLDs in permissions of manifest.json?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Which is the best way for including the following urls (multiple TLDs) in manifest.json of a Chrome Extension? I want to include:

```
https://www.corporate.com/
https://www.corporate.de/
https://www.corporate.co.uk/
```

But the following form gives an error:

```
"permissions": [
    "https://www.corporate.*/",
  ]
```

because the match pattern rules https://developer.chrome.com/apps/match_patterns indicate that the  part can include a * only in the beginning.

Comment: @wOxxOm Does that work for `permissions` too, or only for `content_scripts`? Anyway, if they are only 3 URLs, you can set them explicitly like `"https://www.corporate.com/*","https://www.corporate.de/*","https://www.corporate.co.uk/*"`. Also, there is a trailing comma in the `permissions` list.

Comment: @IvánNokonoko, there can be more than 3 URLs. They will not be 100 for sure, but still if there is an option not to set them explicitly, I would love to know it.

Comment: There's no such option. You can generate the list programmatically, it's trivial.